# synchronization issues of github project with local server

Tags: linux, git, zend-framework, github

I am running apache server on my localhost (mac). There is a project on github which I tried to pull in my local folder.
    git pull
    Already up-to-date.
But, the problem is i can't see any updates when i check it on browser, localhost/directoryname.

I tried to change SSH key. global file for git.
    git config --edit --global

Everything is fine. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Did you checkout the correct branch?

Comment: Yes.. I tried it by using this command: git pull branch_name   ..  But, nothing's happen..

Answer (score 0):

did you try to clone the repository

```
clone git@github.com:blabla.git
```